# Google Earth embebed, create grid layout in Satellite view

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, maps, google-earth

I'm working currently in a project where we need to create a new feature that allow to the user zoom in a Google Earth map embedded in a web app, and create a grid layout over the map, so the user should be able to "mark" some elements of the maps, for example, some specific buildings etc. But we need to create kind of square around the element, so it is not a single point, but at least 3 or 4 as needed to round the element.

We need to save those elements map with its coordinates and assign an ID to every element of the created grid.

Is it that possible? Is there a JS library that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

Google Earth does not currently make an API or embedding available.  If you don't need the full 3D view, then you can do this with the Google Maps API.  There is a "drawing" library available that you can use to draw objects on the map. More info here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer